# Jquery for validate 2 fields when a value changes

Tags: jquery

I have two fields - tare weight and cargo weight. If I change any values, the sum should be within 5000. If I entered a value more than that, this two fields should highlight and error should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#first").change(function(){
  var one = $('#first').val();
  var two = $('#second').val();
  
  if (one + two > 5000)
  {
    $("input").addClass("error");
   }
});
$("#second").change(function(){
  var one = $('#first').val();
  var two = $('#second').val();
  
  if (one + two > 5000)
  {
    $("input").addClass("error");
   }
});
```

```css
.error{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="first" type="number" placeholder="first number" />
<input id="second" type="number" placeholder="second number" />
```

Hope that's what you were looking for